# Google Sheets Macro That Open a Form and that Form get information from another cell in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, macros

Long shot but here we go:
I can do a lot of thing on excel, using VBA. Recently my company start using Google Sheets and I'm lost. We have a file where each can or cannot have a observation. What I'm trying to achieve is, when I double click on a specific cell, on another sheet (on the same file) I will write the key of that line in a cell. Other cells will have a formula to do a vlookup of this key and find information of it. After writing the key, a form opens and show the information vlookup got.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Comment: You are asking about every step on a complete system but 1) StackOverflow has a general rule of one topic per question, 2) there are some things that you need to do to enable any solution to work, and 3) much of the answer will require one or more apps scripts.   Also, some of your requirements are vague or unclear (don't worry, not surprising). I suggest that you start with developing a proto-type (build a spreadsheet, build the lookup data, build a form, show where the lookup data will go in the form. If you have any specific problems as you go, post a specific question.

Comment: I'll do that! Thank you!